Are IDs, IPs, or onion addresses of nodes with whom there have been issues shared between many different lightning service providers?
Are IDs, IPs, or onion addresses of nodes with whom lightning service providers had
issues, e.g. force-closures, shared between many different lightning service providers?
I don't mean here simply sharing between various nodes of the same entity but rather sharing between the nodes of separate entities (e.g. between ACINQ and Wallet_of_Satoshi).

As some force closes can be detected on chain and as public Channels are announced on gossip there is a large part of the data you are interested in already publicly available

This answer could be improved with links to specific places where this data can be found.

The onchain data can be read with the bitcoin software https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/ and historic channel data is available at https://github.com/lnresearch/topology lightning gossip is available through your favourite LN implementation
